# my worries for aws billing(using elastic beanstalk, s3, route53, rds, registrar), do they usually charge this much? or am I off?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just started using elastic beanstalk this week, and they already charged me 11.56$. Registrar for $11 which assumes because I bought my domain here. and $0.51 for route 53. I see this increasing every time I check for billing, what exactly are they charging me for? whatever rds they charge me $0.01, and for s3 I have already exceeded free tier limit....do they charge for every thing or am I just being stingy?

Comment: We can't really tell whether the charges are reasonable, we don't have enough information about your usage rates.  You should check your account's [billing page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home) for usage details.  You may also be interested in checking out [Amazon's AWS Cost Calculator](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/estimate-your-c/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it rather does sound like you are being a bit stingy, or perhaps more accurately that you are purchasing services without familiarizing yourself with the pricing -- all of which is clearly documented and publicly available.

Yes, AWS does "charge for everything" *you actually use*, but they also charge for nothing you don't.

Everything on AWS, with few exceptions, is billed according to usage.

In S3, for example, 1 Gigabyte-Month is roughly $0.03.  So, if you store 1 gigabyte of data for 30 days (1 × 30), that's $0.03... but if you store 30 gigabytes of data for 1 day (30 × 1), that is *also* going to cost $0.03.

You registered a domain. Pricing varies, but $11 (per year) seems reasonable.

You have a hosted zone in Route 53.  That's $0.50 (per month) per hosted zone for each of the first 25 you create, with a steep discount after that ... a pretty sweet deal for reserving your domain a spot on a global network of anycast-routed DNS servers.

Your hosted zone would also handle queries, which are $0.40 per million.  That number shouldn't be prorated, so I'm not sure where the $0.01 is coming from, without seeing the detail.

See [Understanding Your Usage with Billing Reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html).  Every line item has a valid explanation and corresponds to published pricing.

They aren't out to squeeze you for every last cent -- quite the opposite -- you are *only* paying for what you actually use.

See also [AWS Cloud Pricing Principles](https://aws.amazon.com/pricing/) for perhaps a clearer understanding of the pay-as-you-go model.

Comment: sorry can somebody confirm that if i transfer my domain to aws i still need to activate the hosted zone with another service in order to use route53 for example with heroku ??? Thanks